# How do I update my tables in Big Query SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Following is my Query:

```
SELECT* 
FROM project-.table_name
  ALTER TABLE 'table_name' 
  ADD COLUMN ride_lengths TIMESTAMP (HH:MM:SS) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A'; –
```

After executing I am getting the following error:

> Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [3:2]

I expected to create a new column to insert the arithmetic calculations I will perform. There is a hard stop due to a syntax error that I cannot debug.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think setting timestamp format is allowed while adding a new column.

Also, you can't have new column as not null, coz you already have data in your table, and so this new column should need to have some data as well, if you set not null.

following should work.

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ADD COLUMN ride_lengths TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding, I tried that syntax but the same error message will not allow me to proceed with running the code. There is a red flag  after the table name with an error message of "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [9:1].  Line 9 is where I list the table name in. Do you mind if I show a screenshot ?

Comment: yes, please. also try to copy your table id by right clicking on table and use that in query.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for updating tables in BigQuery is pretty standard:
The first part is letting BigQuery know which table you want to update:

```
ALTER TABLE <project-id>.<dataset-id>.<table-id>
```

Then, you can perform different types of alterations to your table, such as adding a column as you are trying to do:

```
ADD COLUMN <column_name> <column_type>
```

The error you received is not about the column itself but rather the syntax of your command, having some form of unclosed string literal.

If you want please send us the exact query you are trying to run and we can help you locate the issue, but the syntax is overall fine.

Note 2 important points:

- 'N/A' is not a timestamp, therefore can not be used as a default value for a timestamp column
- You can not add REQUIRED columns to existing tables. You can add the column as nullable, update the required values, and migrate the data to a new table where the column is defined as REQUIRED.

See more information in the official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#add_an_empty_column

Comment: Ah I see, I just went back and edited sheets to add the column that way I did not need to change the column names in SQL. Next, I am trying to join two tables:                                    SELECT*
FROM
  `cylistic_bikes.2019_biketrips` 
FULL JOIN `cyclistic_bikes.2020_biketrips`
ON `cyclistic_bikes.2019_biketrips.trip_id` = `cyclistic_bikes.2020_biketrips.ride_id`;

Comment: The error message reads: Not found: Dataset ayo-1st-sql-project-4223:cylistic_bikes was not found in location US

Comment: What have I done wrong, here?, the platform is Big Query still.

Comment: The error message you received is providing you with the feedback you need - in this case, it states that the dataset 'cylistic_bikes' was not found in your dataset in Location US.

This is due to a typing error that you have on your first table name in the "FROM" clause. You wrote 'cylistic_bikes' instead of 'cyclistic_bikes'